# create local variables accessible to all the prototype functions

Tags: javascript, prototype

I'm trying to use prototype to add functions to an object, I thought I understand the whole concept, so here's what I did:

```
function ImgContainer() {
    var current_image = 1;
}

ImgContainer.prototype = {
    init: function() {
        //initialize
    },
    scrollLeft: function(){
        //scroll left
    }
}

var imgContainer = new ImgContainer();
```

I assume I can access current_image in both init and scrollLeft, but I'm getting Uncaught ReferenceError: current_image is not defined.

What should I do to have a variable that's accessible in both init and scrollLeft function?

Comment: You *can't* access the variable in `init` or `scrollLeft` because it is not in lexical scope (that is, neither `init` nor `scrollLeft` are in the `ImageContainer` function) .. when using [[prototype]] I find it easier to use properties (e.g. `this.current_image`), and not variables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would add it as a property of the instantiated objects:

```
function ImgContainer() {
    this.current_image = 1;
}
```

Then access the property in the functions:

```
ImgContainer.prototype = {
    init: function() {
        alert(this.current_image);
    },
    scrollLeft: function(){
        //scroll left
    }
}
```

You can still use short lived variables inside methods to store stuff temporarily to get that method's job done. But you store the object's state in its properties.

Comment: thanks! one other question, if I have another function inside init, and that also has to access current_image, what should I do? I already use a local variable in init to store current_image, but I can't access that too since it's again out of scope...

Comment: @shibbydoo You should not have functions inside functions, but just methods. Regardless, the function inside init could access property just as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can't reach private members of an object via prototype methods outside the object because they are out of the scope. You should do it like this:

```
function ImgContainer() {
    var current_image = 1;
    this.init = function() {
        current_image = 'something_blahblah';
    }
}

var imgContainer = new ImgContainer();
```

Comment: They are not members of an object, they're normal variables.

Comment: But we can consider them as private members since they are usable as long as the object exists. I call them as private ^_^

Comment: Well yeah but there is a difference between a variable and object property. Object properties are `delete`able for instance. There is also a huge arsenal of methods that deal with object properties. There's setters, getters, defineProperty etc etc.

Comment: Hmm, I don't know much about delete in javascript and I've never used it before in js. I'll learn this :)

Comment: With this method, prototypical inheritance cannot be used. Since the OP is asking about prototypes specifically, and makes no mention of needing private variables, I would assume this is not what they are looking for.

Comment: I was going to delete my answer but there are some useful information in the comments of my answer so I didn't delete.